# confusion regarding order $4$ element in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given $G= \mathbb{Z_{16}} \times \mathbb{Z_2} $ .   find the number of element of order of $4$ in $G$.

My try :  order $4$ are  lcm$(4,1)$ and lcm $(4,2)$  so there  are  total $ 4$ element  of order $4$ in G but  my teacher said me that  there  are  total $ 6$ element  of order $4$ in $G $

Im confused  where im wrong

Im right/wrong Pliz  tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements $(4,1), (4,0), (12,0)$ and $(12,1)$ are the only elements of order $4$.

The order of $(a,b)\in\Bbb Z_{16}\times\Bbb Z_2$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

Both elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ have order dividing $2$.  Meanwhile, $\Bbb Z_{16}$ has two elements of order $4$.  They are $4$ and $12$.

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ don't have both order $2$, of course, just one of them.

Comment: Oh yeah.  My mistake. @egreg